# resuse code/assign different values to a function in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to find a way for this. I have this long complicated code (below is just a tiny snippet for example purposes) which I want to reuse 30 times in the same file (to put into context it is a product page file)

```
<a href="<?php echo $products['product_x']['url'];?>"><?php echo $products['product_x']['name'];?></a>
```

The `$products['product_x']['url']` refers to a multidimensional array which is in a separate file and loaded into all pages of the site. I am wondering if manipulate the product_x in such a way that allows me to place  the code above in a separate file, include it on the main products page and then change `product_x` 30 times over to load all products. It is obvious that each product has it's own ID.

```
$products['product_x'] 
$products <-- name of the main array
$products['product_x'] <-- each product has it's own array
$products['product_x']['url'] <-- example of information stored in the array
```

The coding on this page for each product is over 100 lines long for each product, as there are various parameters to take into account. is it possible to put the *generic code* into a file and refer to it 30 times changing the value each time?

I have 30 products, which I want to show on a single product page. they are each controlled by their ids (e.g. `product_1`, `product_2` etc). i want to reuse to code and change these ids each time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. I would put all the generic code in a function actually, and call the function to do whatever you want to the product:

```
function process_product($product)
  {
  // do whatever
  return $edited_product
  }

// call it:
$processed = process_product($products['product_x'] );
```

Comment: i'm a novice php programmer, how would i go about doing this? and also, 'product_x' is the item i wish to change 30 times over as well, to correspond with the repsective product.

Comment: Hm.. Did I not just show you how to define the function? Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, I'll have to make a few assumptions, but they might get you close.

It seems to me that you shouldn't have to change products for every iteration of a product.  Surely products all share similar attributes and are found in the same database table.  If not, perhaps that's something to consider.  If so, psuedo-code for your solution would look something like:

```
<?php

$products = $db->fetchAllProducts();

foreach ($products as $product): 
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $product['url'];?>"><?php echo $product['name'];?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You might create a class that defines your products and iterator over that.  The benefit is you'll have a standard interface to use as you iterate.

Comment: Please add a comment describing the downvote.  Not sure what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: The OP does not want to iterate through the `products`, but instead only wants to display a single product on any particular page! Kinda like the `show product` page.

Comment: @Stoic The sentence "... change product_x 30 times over to *load all products*." seems to imply a solution like mine might be simpler overall.  If OP didn't want a solution in regards to all his products, perhaps that shouldn't have been included in the question.  I assert the downvote is invalid.

Comment: i have 30 products, which i want to show on a single product page. they are each controlled by their ids (e.g. product_1, product_2 etc). i want to reuse the block of code and change these ids each time.

Comment: @aqibjr1 A multi-dimensional array of product data implies iteration.  You can iterate over your products in three lines *based on the data and code sample provided in your question.*

Comment: @JeremyKendall: removed the downvote, as it seems that the OP is not clear enough. Sorry, for the confusion :)

Comment: @Stoic No worries. Thanks for reconsidering, but the downvote is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can create a separate PHP file, with a function similar to the following and then, include that file any number of times while passing in the product id/name:

```
// lets say, this file is info.php
function information_for_product_named($name) {
    $html  = "";
    $html .= "<a href='{$products['product_x']['url']}'>{$products['product_x']['name']}</a>";
    // .. and so on...
    echo $html;
}
```

Now, you can do something like this, in your product pages:

```
require_once('info.php');
information_for_product_named('product_x');
```

Nice, and subtle :)

Comment: trying to implement this, but getting an error: "Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/homeovi4/public_html/beta/beta.php on line 5"

Comment: @aqibjr1: yeah, i am sorry. Had a slight error in the second part of the code. Please, try this again.